# Fix media height to container size

Tags: css, wordpress, squarespace

I am currently using Semplice inside of Wordpress. I am trying to create an image gallery slideshow, using both vertical and horizontal oriented photographs. I would like it to perform similar to how Squarespace handles its media sizes. In wordpress, the container is sizing itself to the vertical images, and I would like it to size to the horizontally oriented images.

my wordpress example: https://davidmatthewfiser.com/wedding/keely-aaron-test

the squarespace example: https://justinemontigny.com/lake-willoughby-vermont-wedding

is there a good way to set the container size and have the vertical images scale down, with the negative space on the sides?

thanks!

Comment: You could try setting `height` in `.sgs-slide.original img` selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add this to your theme's custom CSS:

```
.content-block img {
  max-height: 800px;
}
```

And set the max-height to however many px you want.

Comment: thank you! this worked for resizing the container, but now the vertical images are getting stretched to fit.

Comment: @DavidFiser can you explain how they are getting stretched?

Comment: it should be visible now if you want to see. the aspect ratio is getting stretched on the vertical images that are bigger than the container. second image is an example. sorry, coding newbie here! @john

Comment: @DavidFiser are you using a caching plugin?  If so can you clear your cache and look again?

Comment: i added a width: auto code and it works now! thank you for your help

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped.